# Using siunitx, fixed column width with array

Tags: siunitx, width

I want to have a table with width of `\textwidth` so i built a table like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}       % Tabellenlinien
\usepackage{colortbl}           % farbige Tabellen
\usepackage{array}              % Spaltenformate in Tabllen besser formatieren
\usepackage{dcolumn}            % dots seperation in columns
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[binary-units=true]{siunitx}     % SI Einheiten
    \sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} % Centered Columns
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} % Left Columns
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} % Right Columns

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
            \begin{tabular}
                {C{0.15\textwidth} C{0.2\textwidth} C{0.15\textwidth}C{0.15\textwidth}  C{0.35\textwidth}}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Klasse} & \textbf{Ausfall Prozent}  & \multicolumn{2}{C{0.3\textwidth}}{\textbf{Ausfall Zeit/Monat}}    & \textbf{Ausfall Zeit/Jahr}\\
                \midrule 
                2   &   99,0 \% & \multicolumn{1}{R{0.15\textwidth}}{438} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\,min}       & 87,7 h (ca. 3,5 Tage) \\
                3   &   99,9 \% & \multicolumn{1}{R{0.15\textwidth}}{43,8} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\,min}      & 8:45 h \\
                4   &   99,99 \% & \multicolumn{1}{R{0.15\textwidth}}{4,38} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\,min}     & 52:36 min \\
                5   &   99,999 \% & \multicolumn{1}{R{0.15\textwidth}}{26,3} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\,s}      & 5:16 min \\
                6   &   99,9999 \% & \multicolumn{1}{R{0.15\textwidth}}{2,63} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\,s}     & 31,6 s \\
                \bottomrule 
            \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

This looks like that:
[image]

But i dont like the way, the numbers are aligned.. so i want to align them to the ","

I tried to use `\siunitx` and it worked fine, but now i dont know how to set the width of the columns like above with `C{0.2\textwidth}` and the multicolumn solution isnt my favorite.. so i tried with `\siunitx`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

    \usepackage{booktabs}       % Tabellenlinien
    \usepackage{colortbl}           % farbige Tabellen
    \usepackage{array}              % Spaltenformate in Tabllen besser formatieren
    \usepackage{dcolumn}            % dots seperation in columns
    \usepackage{tabularx}

    \usepackage[binary-units=true]{siunitx}     % SI Einheiten
        \sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} % Centered Columns
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} % Left Columns
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} % Right Columns

    \begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}
        {C{0.15\textwidth}  S[table-format=2.4]     S[table-format=3.1]     C{0.35\textwidth}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Klasse} & {\textbf{Ausfall Prozent}}    & {\textbf{Ausfall Zeit/Monat}}         & \textbf{Ausfall Zeit/Jahr}\\
        \midrule 
        2   &   99,0\,\si{\percent}     & 438,0\,\si{\minute}   & 87,7 h (ca. 3,5 Tage) \\
        3   &   99,9\,\si{\percent}     &  43,8\,\si{\minute}   & 8:45 h \\
        4   &   99,99\,\si{\percent}    &   4,4\,\si{\minute}   & 52:36 min \\
        5   &   99,999\,\si{\percent}   &  26,3\,\si{\second}   & 5:16 min \\
        6   &   99,9999\,\si{\percent}  &   2,6\,\si{\second}   & 31,6 s \\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

But the 2nd column is now `overfull` as you can see. I want to set the width to `C{0.2\textwidth}` but i dont know how.. The table also doesnt has the full size of `\textwidth`
[image]

---

EDIT:

With help of **LaRiFaRi** i edited my tex file. Thanks a lot!!!

It now looks like this:
[image]
It is left aligned and doesnt has the size of the `\textwidth`
Also there is no space between the next line

---

**EDIT:**
Centering is working now!

The whole size of the table isnt at `\textwidth`, but it should be.
How can i set the size of the columns by hard?

sth like `0.25\textwidth 0.25\textwidth 0.5\textwidth` so all together its `1.0\textwidth`
the whole area shuld also be "filled" with the table

[image]

---

**EDIT 3:**
Problem Solved!

@Zarka I forgot to say, that there is `\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}` in my preamble

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{threeparttable}
    \centering
    \caption[Verfügbarkeitsklassen nach IEEE]{Verfügbarkeitsklassen nach IEEE}
    \label{tab:verfuegbarkeitsklassen}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
        C{0.15\textwidth} 
        S[table-format=2.5]
        S[table-align-text-post = false,group-four-digits,table-format=5.1]
        S[table-align-text-post = false,group-four-digits,table-format=7.1]
        }
        \toprule
\textbf{Klasse} 
    & \mcx{Ausfall in \%} 
                & \mcx{Ausfallzeit/Monat in s} 
                                    & \mcx{Ausfallzeit/Jahr in s} \\
        \midrule
2   &  99,0     & 26280,0\tnote{1}  & 315720,0\tnote{2} \\
3   &  99,9     &  2628,0           &  30420,0\tnote{3} \\
4   &  99,99    &   264,0           &   3141,6          \\
5   &  99,999   &    26,3           &    909,6          \\
6   &  99,9999  &     2,6           &     31,6          \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[1] entspricht \SI{438}{\minute} oder \SI{7.3}{\hour}
        \item[2] entspricht \SI{87.7}{\hour} bzw.\ etwa \num{3.5} Tagen
        \item[3] entspricht \SI{8.45}{\hour}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable and as minimal as possible. Thanks.

Comment: I have limited it to the most necessary

Comment: Rather then  `{\textbf{Ausfall Prozent}}` try with `\parbox{0.2\textwidth}{\centering\textbf{Ausfall Prozent}}`

Comment: this doesnt work.. the whole size of the table isnt `\textwidth` ant the horizontal alignment is now aligned to the bottom. the size of the column didnt change to `.2\textwidth`

Comment: i want to have something like that `c{.2\textwidth}{S[table-format=2.4]}` i know its not working like that, but i want to set the size of the column and use `siunitx` with the `S` argument

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your table is hard to read, as it stands right now. May I recommend:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}    
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=DE}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\tnote
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption[Verfügbarkeitsklassen nach IEEE]{Verfügbarkeitsklassen nach IEEE}
    \label{tab:verfuegbarkeitsklassen2}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{%
        >{\centering\arraybackslash$}X<{$} 
        S[table-format=2.5]     
        S[table-align-text-post = false,group-four-digits,table-format=5.1]
        S[table-format=7.1]
        }
        \toprule
        \textbf{Kl.} & {\textbf{Ausfall in \%}} & {\textbf{Ausfallzeit/Monat (s)}} & \textbf{Ausfallzeit/Jahr (s)} \\
        \midrule 
        2 &  99,0    & 26280,0\tnote{1} & 315720.0\tnote{2} \\
        3 &  99,9    &  2628,0          & 30420.0\tnote{3}  \\
        4 &  99,99   &   264,0          & 3141.6            \\
        5 &  99,999  &    26,3          & 909.6             \\
        6 &  99,9999 &     2,6          & 31,6              \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[1] entspricht \SI{438}{\minute} oder \SI{7.3}{\hour}
        \item[2] entspricht \SI{87.7}{\hour} bzw.\ etwa \num{3.5} Tagen
        \item[3] entspricht \SI{8.45}{\hour}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: looks much more better!  but the whole table isnt at the size of `\textwidth` and the width of the columns is very "small"

Comment: @dynamicman The column of the whole text area? You should show this in your example. I would never go for fixed width, unless it is needed. Try to keep your tables consistent in spacing, font size and so on. When you tell me, how small your column is, I will fix it for you. In the example above, it would help a lot to abbreviate "Ausfall" for the last three columns. Or you get rid of the word "Klasse" and describe that in your caption.

Comment: In the default article page layout the table is wide than text width. To align it with text width it is necessary to write column headers in two lines or reduce headers' fonts.

Comment: @dynamicman you were right, I did not see, it was too wide in my example. I have mentioned some fixings and alike did Zarko. And I have adapted my code a bit. I have also introduce some vertical space (forgot) the `\end{table}`...)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi our Professor wants us to size pictures, tables, ... to the size of the textwidth (the whole table). Now the table looks nice, but the whole table width != textwidth ... The centering is now working i added `\centering` after the `\begin{table}`

Comment: @dynamicman strange specification but no problem :-) See my last edit.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi what does `>{\centering\arraybackslash$}X<{$}` do ? To be precise the `X<{$}`

Comment: @dynamicman it is setting the whole table in math mode. The numbers should be in mathmode here. This will have no visual effect for most documents. But if you copy this table to some `beamer` later on, you will notice that's better.

Answer (score 2):

As supplement to nice *LaRiFaRi* answer. I to it add/change two things:

- add package `geometry` and set margigns to 25mm
- add package `tabularx` and for table headers define `\newcommand` which as column type use modified `X` column type.

With this two measure table with is equal to text width:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,  % <-- to show page layout
            margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}{\textbf{#1}}}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=DE}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\tnote

\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \centering
    \caption[Verfügbarkeitsklassen nach IEEE]{Verfügbarkeitsklassen nach IEEE}
    \label{tab:verfuegbarkeitsklassen2}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
        c 
        S[table-format=2.5]
        S[table-align-text-post = false,group-four-digits,table-format=5.1]
        S[table-align-text-post = false,group-four-digits,table-format=7.1]
        }
        \toprule
\textbf{Klasse} 
    & \mcx{Ausfall in \%} 
                & \mcx{Ausfallzeit/Monat in s} 
                                    & \mcx{Ausfallzeit/Jahr in s} \\
        \midrule
2   &  99,0     & 26280,0\tnote{1}  & 315720,0\tnote{2} \\
3   &  99,9     &  2628,0           &  30420,0\tnote{3} \\
4   &  99,99    &   264,0           &   3141,6          \\
5   &  99,999   &    26,3           &    909,6          \\
6   &  99,9999  &     2,6           &     31,6          \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[1] entspricht \SI{438}{\minute} oder \SI{7.3}{\hour}
        \item[2] entspricht \SI{87.7}{\hour} bzw.\ etwa \num{3.5} Tagen
        \item[3] entspricht \SI{8.45}{\hour}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i do like your solution! forgot to say, that there is `\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}` in my peambel ...sry :-D the last thing, that is wrong, is the headline of the first column... its left aligned.. but i dont know why.. i will edit my first post..

Comment: My fault... everything is workning fine now!

Answer (score 1):

To obtain table with width of `\textwidth` you can insert text in header within a parbox where the sum of all widths of  boxes is equal to `\textwidth`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}    
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=DE}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\tnote

\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \centering
    \caption[Verfügbarkeitsklassen nach IEEE]{Verfügbarkeitsklassen nach IEEE}
    \label{tab:verfuegbarkeitsklassen2}
    \begin{tabular}{%
        @{}S[table-format=1.0]  
        @{}S[table-format=2.5]     
        @{}S[table-align-text-post = false,group-four-digits,table-format=5.1]
        @{}S[table-format=7.1]@{}
        }
        \toprule
        \parbox{.15\textwidth}{\centering\bfseries Klasse} &
        \parbox{.2\textwidth} {\centering\bfseries Ausfall in \%} &
        \parbox{.30\textwidth}{\centering\bfseries Ausfallzeit/Monat in s} &
        \parbox{.35\textwidth}{\centering\bfseries Ausfallzeit/Jahr in s} \\
        \midrule 
        2 &  99,0    & 26280,0\tnote{1} & 315720.0\tnote{2} \\
        3 &  99,9    &  2628,0          & 30420.0\tnote{3}  \\
        4 &  99,99   &   264,0          & 3141.6            \\
        5 &  99,999  &    26,3          & 909.6             \\
        6 &  99,9999 &     2,6          & 31,6              \\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[1] entspricht \SI{438}{\minute} oder \SI{7.3}{\hour}
        \item[2] entspricht \SI{87.7}{\hour} bzw.\ etwa \num{3.5} Tagen
        \item[3] entspricht \SI{8.45}{\hour}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need complicated setup with `tabularx`: it's much easier with `tabular*`, that adds space between the columns.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}    
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=DE}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\ts}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption[Verfügbarkeitsklassen nach IEEE]{Verfügbarkeitsklassen nach IEEE}
\label{tab:verfuegbarkeitsklassen2}

\sisetup{
  group-four-digits=true,
  group-digits=integer,
}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{%
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
  c
  S[table-format=2.4]
  S[table-space-text-post=\ts{1},table-format=5.1]
  S[table-space-text-post=\ts{1},table-format=6.1]
}
\toprule
\textbf{Kl.} &
  {\textbf{Ausfall}} &
  {\textbf{Ausfallzeit/Monat}} &
  {\textbf{Ausfallzeit/Jahr}} \\
& {(\%)} & {(\si{s})} & {(\si{s})} \\
\midrule 
2 &  99,0    & 26280,0\ts{1} & 315720.0\ts{2} \\
3 &  99,9    &  2628,0       & 30420.0\ts{3}  \\
4 &  99,99   &   264,0       & 3141.6         \\
5 &  99,999  &    26,3       & 909.6          \\
6 &  99,9999 &     2,6       & 31,6           \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\ts{1} entspricht \SI{438}{\minute} oder \SI{7.3}{\hour}}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\ts{2} entspricht \SI{87.7}{\hour} bzw.\ etwa \num{3.5} Tagen}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\ts{3} entspricht \SI{8.45}{\hour}}
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]